# Strange behaviour of awk

Tags: awk

I have encountered the following behaviour of awk, which has me pretty baffled:

```
echo "" | awk '{print 15}'
```

outputs

```
15
```

BUT:

```
echo "" | awk '{print 015}'
```

outputs

```
13
```

Replacing 015 with 013, 0013, 0105 and 0130 yields 11, 11, 69 and 88, respectively. Floating point numbers work as expected, with or without leading zeroes.

I have observed this behaviour for GNU Awk versions 3.1.7, 4.0.2 and 4.1.3.

Can anyone make sense of this?

Comment: 15 in base 8 == 13 in base 10.

Comment: See here:  https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nondecimal_002dnumbers.html

Comment: Ok that explains it

Comment: @jas, thank you for sharing it I was looking for it then finally written by myself, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That is expected `015` is being considered as Octal value.

```
echo "" | awk '{print 015}' ##Octal
13
echo "" | awk '{print 15}'  ##Decimal
15
echo "" | awk '{print 0x15}' ##Hex
21
```

***EDIT:*** Adding nice link posted by jas in comments too here https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nondecimal_002dnumbers.html

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip: if you want to execute some awk code without needing any input, use the BEGIN block

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    print 015
    print 15
    print 0x15
}'
```

```
13
15
21
```